# Can't remove stems to replace washers

Tags: shower, valve

I have a two handle shower that is very hard to completely turn off. From what I've found, it appears the washer on the back of the stems needs to be replaced. Watched some videos and it all looks pretty easy. I removed the knob with no issue. But when I went to remove the stem, the nut is back behind the tile of the shower wall. Even if I could manage to unscrew it, I don't know if it would come out of the hole in the tile. Any suggestions aside from either calling a plumber or cutting the tile? No access panel on the other side, just drywall there.

Comment: Please post a picture of the unit, or brand at least

Comment: Usually there's some metal "guard" that you can unscrew to allow easier access.  Pictures would help...I mean it's possible they tiled over it, in which case...maybe you can cut some of the tile out more with a dremel or something...